# PHP and MySQL IP Ban system Problems

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, ip

I am currently trying to create an IP-BAN system in PHP AND MYSQL, however I'm not very familiar with MySQL syntax. This is my code so far, and it returns the last one, "uh-oh".
   Code:

```
<?php

    $ip = '127.0.0.1';

    mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass');
    mysql_select_db('IP');

    if(mysql_query("SELECT IP FROM IP WHERE IP='127.0.0.1'") == 1){
        echo "If you get this, it may or may not be working";
    }
    elseif(mysql_query("SELECT IP FROM IP WHERE IP='127.0.0.1'") == FALSE){
        echo "If you get this, it means that your IP was not found in the database";
    }
    else{
        echo "Uh-oh!";
    }
```

My SQL database name is IP, and the table name is IP, and the fields are IP and ban.

How would I make this code tell me whether the given IP is in the table or not?

Comment: * Use PDO. Trust me, I'm an engineer.
* Why you declare `$ip` if you're duplicating its value later?
* `mysql_query` returns resource handle. You'll want to check result using `mysql_fetch_*()`. Use PDO, again.
* You're selecting `IP` field from `IP` table from `IP` database. This will hurt you. I promise.

Comment: banning ip's why? you know ip != person

Comment: I prefer not to let a banned user use up my MySQL resources. You should consider implementing this at the file level.

Answer (score 5):

`mysql_query()` will return `FALSE` if the query fails with a syntax error, but it won't return `FALSE`  if the value is not found.  Instead, both cases will return a result resource.  You must check the value of [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to find out if a row was returned.

```
// Do the query and test for errors:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT IP FROM IP WHERE IP='127.0.0.1'");
if (!$result ) {
  // Query error
  echo mysql_error();
}
// Query was successful - test if any rows were found
else {
  if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     //the IP was found
  }
  else {
     // the IP was NOT found (num rows === 0)
  }
}
```

###Disclaimers:

Now, about the practice of banning by IP... It is generally not recommended to do this.  School or business networks, or anyone behind a NAT by their ISP (like many mobile networks) share one public IP between many many users (perhaps even thousands).  You cannot identify an individual user by IP address reliably, and worse, you risk preventing legitimate users from using your web application.

And finally, about the `mysql_*()` functions themselves..  The PHP development community has begun planning the deprecation of these old functions as they don't encourage secure coding practices well.  Instead, I (and most everyone else here) recommend familiarizing yourself with a modern API making use of prepared statements instead.  I prefer [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), but [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is an option as well.

Answer (score -1):

mysql_query() returns a resource if it is successful. Use the examples on this page:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php